# How to get rid of these contacts numbers in a group

Tags: ios, contacts

How would I get rid of the two middle contacts In this group? I am new to iPhone and just transferred from an android when these contacts popped up in this group. They were never there before and am assuming it was a mix up during the contact transfer process.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried swiping left?

Comment: @Allan yes, swiping left worked for other conversations but did nothing for this one

Comment: Then, that group was created outside of the iPhone.  If you created the group in Gmail, for example, you have to edit it there.

Comment: @Allan I just realized that this was not a group text on my android. It added these numbers in the transfer process.